# Bending library and pfgpathquadraticcurveto don't play well together

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, pgf-core

I'm working on an arrowhead that encompasses a path.

As long as the path is straight, it works well.

When the path is curved, `\pgfpathquadraticcurveto` produces some weird results.  It appears that the first quadratic curve takes a control point from the bend somehow.  In the MWE, the curve that goes from the barb down to the shaft gets a control point that appears to be part of the bending control point.
[image: arrows with distorted barb]

If we change the barb to a line, instead of a quadratic curve, then the shaft gets distorted.

[image: arrows with distorted shaft]

Any ideas for working around this problem?  Or troubleshooting it?  It looks like a bug to me, but I'm new enough at tikz/pgf to be unsure.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\newlength{\mypathlength}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{stashlength}{final}{
  \state{final}{
     \setlength{\mypathlength}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
     %\pgftext{\mypathlength}
     \global\mypathlength=\mypathlength}}




\newdimen\pgftaillength % Length of tail of arrow
\newdimen\pgfheadlength % length of arrow head
\newdimen\pgfheadwidth  % half width of arrow shaft where it connects to head
\newdimen\pgftaildepth  % depth of circular dip in tail

\pgfkeys{/pgf/arrow keys/tail length/.code=
  \newdimen\somedimen
  \pgfmathsetlength{\somedimen}{#1}
  \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter
    {\expandafter\pgftaillength\expandafter=\the\somedimen}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/arrow keys/head length/.code=
  \newdimen\somedimen
  \pgfmathsetlength{\somedimen}{#1}
  \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter
    {\expandafter\pgfheadlength\expandafter=\the\somedimen}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/arrow keys/head width/.code=
  \newdimen\somedimen
  \pgfmathsetlength{\somedimen}{#1}
  \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter
    {\expandafter\pgfheadwidth\expandafter=\the\somedimen}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/arrow keys/tail depth/.code=
  \newdimen\somedimen
  \pgfmathsetlength{\somedimen}{#1}
  \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter
    {\expandafter\pgftaildepth\expandafter=\the\somedimen}}

\pgfdeclarearrow{%
  name=networkarrow,
  parameters={%
    \the\pgfarrowlength,
    \the\pgfarrowwidth,
    \the\pgftaillength,
    \the\pgfheadlength,
    \the\pgfheadwidth,
    \the\pgftaildepth
  },
  setup code={%
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{0pt}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.9\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-\pgfarrowlength}
    % The hull
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{0pt}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfheadwidth}
    %\pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    % Saves: All the necessary parameters
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowwidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgftaillength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfheadlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfheadwidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgftaildepth
  },
  drawing code={%
    %\pgftext{\mypathlength}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}} % tip of arrow
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{ -\pgfheadlength-.5\pgftaildepth}
                            {.5\pgfheadwidth}} % end of barb
    \pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                            {\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength}
                                      {.5\pgfarrowwidth}}  %shaft/head junction
     % uncomment the next two lines, and comment out the previous 4 to see the
     % problem with \pgfpathquadraticcurveto move to the shaft curve, instead of
     % the head curve                                 
     %\pgflineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength}
     %                                 {.5\pgfarrowwidth}}  %shaft/head junction                                  
    \pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength+\pgftaillength}
                                      {.5\pgfarrowwidth}}
                            {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength-\pgftaildepth}
                                      {.5\pgfheadwidth}}  %tail barb
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                   {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength}{.25\pgfheadwidth}}
                   {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength}{0pt}}  %center of tail
    % mirror image  of top half             
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength}{-.25\pgfheadwidth}}                              
                   {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {-.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                   {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength-\pgftaildepth}
                                      {-.5\pgfheadwidth}}  % back to barb
    \pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength+\pgftaillength}
                                      {-.5\pgfarrowwidth}} 
                            {\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength}
                                      {-.5\pgfarrowwidth}}  % shaft head junction
    \pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {-.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                            {\pgfpoint{ -\pgfheadlength-.5\pgftaildepth}
                            {-.5\pgfheadwidth}} % arrow barb
    % temporarily make half arrow so I have less to fix                       
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqstroke
  },
  defaults={%
    length=0pt,
    width=1.2mm,
    tail length=8mm,
    head length=8mm,
    head width=5mm,
    tail depth=.5mm
  },
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw [-{networkarrow[bend]},preaction={decorate,decoration=stashlength}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
   \draw [-{networkarrow[bend]},preaction={decorate,decoration=stashlength}] (0,-2) to [bend left] (8,-2);

   \draw [-{networkarrow[bend]},preaction={decorate,decoration=stashlength}] (0,-4) to [bend right] (8,-4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have an answer to what causes the problem or how to debug it at the pgf level, I have found a workaround that seems to solve the problem.

Simply make the first curve in the arrow be a `pgfpathcurveto` rather than a `pgfpathquadraticcurveto`.  I did it by doubling the control point.  It's not exactly the same, but close enough for my purposes.

This made all the rest of the curves work properly, which surprised me a little bit.

[image: curved arrows working properly]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\newlength{\mypathlength}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{stashlength}{final}{
  \state{final}{
     \setlength{\mypathlength}{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
     %\pgftext{\mypathlength}
     \global\mypathlength=\mypathlength}}




\newdimen\pgftaillength % Length of tail of arrow
\newdimen\pgfheadlength % length of arrow head
\newdimen\pgfheadwidth  % half width of arrow shaft where it connects to head
\newdimen\pgftaildepth  % depth of circular dip in tail

\pgfkeys{/pgf/arrow keys/tail length/.code=
  \newdimen\somedimen
  \pgfmathsetlength{\somedimen}{#1}
  \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter
    {\expandafter\pgftaillength\expandafter=\the\somedimen}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/arrow keys/head length/.code=
  \newdimen\somedimen
  \pgfmathsetlength{\somedimen}{#1}
  \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter
    {\expandafter\pgfheadlength\expandafter=\the\somedimen}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/arrow keys/head width/.code=
  \newdimen\somedimen
  \pgfmathsetlength{\somedimen}{#1}
  \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter
    {\expandafter\pgfheadwidth\expandafter=\the\somedimen}}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/arrow keys/tail depth/.code=
  \newdimen\somedimen
  \pgfmathsetlength{\somedimen}{#1}
  \expandafter\pgfarrowsaddtooptions\expandafter
    {\expandafter\pgftaildepth\expandafter=\the\somedimen}}

\pgfdeclarearrow{%
  name=networkarrow,
  parameters={%
    \the\pgfarrowlength,
    \the\pgfarrowwidth,
    \the\pgftaillength,
    \the\pgfheadlength,
    \the\pgfheadwidth,
    \the\pgftaildepth
  },
  setup code={%
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{0pt}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.9\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-\pgfarrowlength}
    % The hull
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{0pt}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfheadwidth}
    %\pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    % Saves: All the necessary parameters
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowwidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgftaillength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfheadlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfheadwidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgftaildepth
  },
  drawing code={%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}} % tip of arrow
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{ -\pgfheadlength-.5\pgftaildepth}
                            {.5\pgfheadwidth}} % end of barb
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                   {\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                   {\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength}
                                      {.5\pgfarrowwidth}}  %shaft/head junction
    \pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength+\pgftaillength}
                                      {.5\pgfarrowwidth}}
                            {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength-\pgftaildepth}
                                      {.5\pgfheadwidth}}  %tail barb
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                   {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength}{.25\pgfheadwidth}}
                   {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength}{0pt}}  %center of tail
    % mirror image  of top half             
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength}{-.25\pgfheadwidth}}                              
                   {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {-.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                   {\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength-\pgftaildepth}
                                      {-.5\pgfheadwidth}}  % back to barb
    \pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\mypathlength+\pgftaillength}
                                      {-.5\pgfarrowwidth}} 
                            {\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength}
                                      {-.5\pgfarrowwidth}}  % shaft head junction
    \pgfpathquadraticcurveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfheadlength-.25\pgftaildepth}
                                      {-.375\pgfheadwidth}}
                            {\pgfpoint{ -\pgfheadlength-.5\pgftaildepth}
                            {-.5\pgfheadwidth}} % arrow barb
    % temporarily make half arrow so I have less to fix                       
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqstroke
  },
  defaults={%
    length=0pt,
    width=1.2mm,
    tail length=8mm,
    head length=8mm,
    head width=5mm,
    tail depth=.5mm
  },
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw [-{networkarrow[bend]},preaction={decorate,decoration=stashlength}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
   \draw [-{networkarrow[bend]},preaction={decorate,decoration=stashlength}] (0,-2) to [bend left] (8,-2);

   \draw [-{networkarrow[bend]},preaction={decorate,decoration=stashlength}] (0,-4) to [bend right] (8,-4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```